# Android google maps v2 error

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting 2 errors here,first "Unable to start activity" and the second being "API key not found".I have searched for a lot of solutions but nothing solving the problems.The API key is correct but still i dont know why is the error coming.Can anyone tell me whats wrong in the code?

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.vallabh.googlemapspractice"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.vallabh.googlemapspractice.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyBQeTS1IcCPtJxCGvFC4o-Ud5fJHdUmRCY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBQeTS1IcCPtJxCGvFC4o-Ud5fJHdUmRCY"/>


</application>

</manifest>
```

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post activity code also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyBQeTS1IcCPtJxCGvFC4o-Ud5fJHdUmRCY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBQeTS1IcCPtJxCGvFC4o-Ud5fJHdUmRCY"/>
```

with

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBQeTS1IcCPtJxCGvFC4o-Ud5fJHdUmRCY" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyBQeTS1IcCPtJxCGvFC4o-Ud5fJHdUmRCY"
android:value="AIzaSyBQeTS1IcCPtJxCGvFC4o-Ud5fJHdUmRCY"/>
```

It should be

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyBQeTS1IcCPtJxCGvFC4o-Ud5fJHdUmRCY"/>
```

Make sure your `MainActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`